# Error at app.useMvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am running ASP.NET Vnext web app on VS 2015 CTP5.

I am getting a `TypeLoadException`:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

at this line -

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

These are the dependencies in my project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta2",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.RequestContainer": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta1",
    "AutoMapper": "3.2.1",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.Services": "0.7.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure": "1.0.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache": "",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry": "4.5.1",
    "System.Spatial": "5.6.1",
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "2.0.3",
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching": "2.5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Common": "",
    "Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Data.Common": "",
    "Unity.WebAPI": "5.1",
    "Microsoft.Data.Edm": "5.6.2",
    "Microsoft.Data.OData": "5.6.2",
    "Microsoft.Data.Services.Client": "5.6.2",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "4.3.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8.0",
    "Unity": "3.5.1404.0"
},
```

Comment: What runtime and what package versions are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are referencing system.web this is not supported and you shouldn't do that. Look at your project.json and remove references to system.web or any packages depending on system.web.

Edit:
Specifically Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure references System.Web (and is not supported).

Start by building you app component by component, instead of trying to just copy the references over to project.json.

You can expand the references node in visual studio to see the dependencies each root level dependency brings with it.

Note - No oData support is available for vNext, no Unity support yet either and it will not be Unity.WebAPI when it happens

Comment: Yishai, i have edited the post to have the project.json dependencies. i do not see a reference to system.web there.

Comment: Looks like there is a whole lot of things going on in your app.
For example, Unity and Unity WebAPI are not available for vNext Yet. There is no oData support at the moment. etc. I would start by building up your app from individual components instead of trying to port it wholesale

Comment: Yes, one of the referenced 4.5.1 class library has reference to System.Web and hence probably the error. I am not trying to do a wholesale port per say but it would be hard for me to rewrite the web app since i have a lot of code in my 4.5.1 class libraries which i can reuse. what is the best way to approach this? Should i try and rewrite these class libraries in a ASP.NET Vnext class library?

Comment: As long as you don't rely on System.Web you should be on your way. If you want to end up with one class library, then you should move it to ASP.NET 5.0 library. But you can also break up your class libraries, and just fork the functionality that depends on system.web